# Android check recognized sensors

Tags: android, sensors

i need a little help: how to check recognized sensors?
Because a made a project and on gs2 has all the sensors(acc,gyro, etc.) but on galaxy ace there are only acc as i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.: Get SensorManager:

```
`mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);`
```

2.: Get Sensor list:

```
List< sensor> sensorList = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
```

3.: Print the sensors:

```
for( Sensor s : sensorList) {
 Log.d("sensor", "Name=" + s.getName());
 Log.d("sensor", "Vendor=" + s.getVendor());
 Log.d("sensor", "Version=" + s.getVersion());
 Log.d("sensor", "MaximumRange=" + s.getMaximumRange());
 Log.d("sensor", "MinDelay=" + s.getMinDelay());
 Log.d("sensor", "Power=" + s.getPower());
 Log.d("sensor", "Type=" + s.getType());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely what you are looking for in checking the features programtically

```
PackageManager PM= this.getPackageManager();
boolean gps = PM.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
boolean acc = PM.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
```

This link explains what you can do to filter your application in the marketplace, look specifically at the section

i think i found it...